# angular http get with node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am querying data from mongodb and sending that as a json to a URL

> querying data from mongodb

```
router.get('fillSurvey/:ID', function (req, res) {
    Survey.findOne({_id:req.params.ID}, function ( err, survey, count ){
     res.send(json);
   }); 
});
```

I want to use angular http get to fetch this json data. **The problem I have is what should be the url in angular http get?** 
The problem arises because there is a **/:ID** in the above url.

Comment: `var url = 'fillSurvey/' + 12`  if you wanna get with id = 12

Comment: is there a way to access all IDs that are passed in the url? a common way for all IDs...Because I get the ID in the above code from                                           <a href="SubmitSurvey/<%= survey._id %> .

Comment: just create new router for all survey

Comment: Yes I use express js

Comment: **/:ID** is way to represent the URL contains an id. So you can pass directly 'fillSurvey/id` in angular, Where id should be any id from your application

Answer (score 2):

This is the code of your nodejs.

```
router.get('/fillSurvey/:ID', function (req, res) {
    var ID = req.params.ID;
    Survey.findOne({_id: ID}, function (err, survey) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({status: 0, message: err});
        } else if (!survey) {
            res.json({status: 0, msg: "not found"});
        } else {
            res.json({status: 1, message: survey});
        }
    })
});
```

Now if you want to call this api use the url 
let us assume your id is '1234'

```
"http://localhost:portno/fillSurvey/1234"
```

Answer (score 1):

That will not cause any issue in angularJS.
You can simply access `fillSurvey/id` URL.

Try the below code

```
var data=10; // ID that you want to pass
var requestParam={
  method:"GET",
  params:data,
  url:"fillSurvey/"+data // URL 
}
$http(requestParam).then(function(success){
  console.log(success);
}, function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```